# What permissions are required for each the major Android ad providers?

Tags: android, ads

I'm trying to decide which ad provider to go with and one of my irritations on the market are apps that require more permissions than needed. Most of the major providers require you to sign up before you get access to their documentation, so thought we could compile the information here.

What permissions are required to show ads in your Android app from each of the major ad vendors:

- [AdMob](http://admob.com/)
- [TapJoy](http://www.tapjoy.com/)
- [Google Mobile Ads](http://www.google.com/mobileads/)
- [Burstly](http://www.burstly.com/)
- [Mobclix](http://www.mobclix.com/)
- [zestadz](http://www.zestadz.com/)
- [InMobi](http://www.inmobi.com/)
- [iVdopia](http://ivdopia.com/)

  Feel free to add more. I just got the list from [tutsplus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/articles/marketing/mobile-advertising-services/).

(To be clear, I'm looking to see which vendors require more permissions than others.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I don't think any of them other than Admob just require the INTERNET permission.  Here's my experience (I access most of those other ones through MobClix, so don't know if their APIs have specific requirements):

AdMob, MobClix, and MobFox:
android.permission.INTERNET

MobClix:
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

MobClix and MobFox:
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

MobClix recently removed the permission to view tasks/running apps (SDK version 3.0, which is good (too many permissions and users won't download your app)).

Update:  It looks like MobFox removed the need for the WiFi state and Network state permissions in their 3.0 api.

Also note that there are optional permissions, such as location, that might get better ads for you.

Answer (score 1):

Admob requires `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

I don't see why any other provider would require more than this.

Comment: Advertisers are very interested in location and phone identity.

Comment: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE  is very important one imho. This allows the advertisers SDK to check if there is an active network connection, before wasting times at repeatedly attempting to connect to the server and waste cpu cycles and battery power.

Answer (score 1):

There are few more permissions as described below different providers may use or not use these

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: What does admob require